# How to check a string which only contains one word. If a string has a sentence it should return false

Tags: java, string

I know it's a wierd to ask a question like this. But i've got no options. The problem is
I've come across a requirement where i happens to add a condition where, If there is an input as a string, I should be able to allow all the strings which only contains one word. So if there are many words I should reject.
How to add such check when I don't have specificity on such string.

Comment: what's a word? would they contain whitespace?

Comment: Check for whitespaces in your string .

Comment: @nlloyd it can be any character sequence

Comment: @KishoreKumarKorada perhaps you should add some examples and/or clarify how words are separated in your input strings

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation

Answer (score 8):

If the words are separated by some kind of white space, you could use a simple regular expression for this:

```
Pattern wordPattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+");
Matcher wordMatcher = wordPattern.matcher(inputString);
if (!wordMatcher.matches()) {
    // discard user input
}
```

This will match all word characters (`[a-zA-Z_0-9]`). If your definition of "word" is different, the regex will need to be adapted.

Answer (score 3):

So many ways you can achieve it,
One of the simplest is..

```
String str = "abc def";
String [] array = str.trim().split(" ");
if(array.lenght==1){
// allow if lenght = 1, or a word....
}else{
// don't allow if lenght !=1 , or not a word..., dosomething else, or skip
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on a regular expression that represents a sequence of white spaces and then see how many parts you get. Here's a function to do it:

```
public static boolean is_word(String s) {
    return (s.length() > 0 && s.split("\\s+").length == 1);
}

System.out.println(is_word("word"));
System.out.println(is_word("two words"));
System.out.println(is_word("word\tabc\txyz"));
System.out.println(is_word(""));
```

**Output**:

```
true
false
false
false
```

The length check on the input string is required if you want to say that an empty string is not a word, which would seem reasonable.